# Why compiler skips assigning variable

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have the following procedure :

```
procedure GetDegree(const num : DWORD ; var degree : DWORD ; min ,sec : Extended);
begin
  degree := num div (500*60*60);
  min := num div (500*60) - degree *60;
  sec := num/500 - min *60 - degree *60*60;
end;
```

After degree variable gets assigned the debugger skips to the end of the procedure . Why is that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's an optimisation. The variables `min` and `sec` are passed by value. That means that modifications to them are not seen by the caller and are private to this procedure. Hence the compiler can work out that assigning to them is pointless. The values assigned to the variables can never be read. So the compiler elects to save time and skip the assignments.
I expect that you meant to declare the procedure like this:

```
procedure GetDegree(const num: DWORD; var degree: DWORD; var min, sec: Extended);
```

As I said in your previous question, there's not really much point in using `Extended`. You would be better off with one of the standard floating point types, `Single` or `Double`. Or even using the generic `Real` which maps to `Double`.

Also, you have declared `min` to be of floating point type, but the calculation computes an integer. My answer to your previous question is quite precise in this regard.

---

I would recommend that you create a record to hold these values. Passing three separate variables around makes your function interfaces very messy and breaks encapsulation. These three values only have meaning when consider as a whole.

```
type
  TGlobalCoordinate = record
    Degrees: Integer;
    Minutes: Integer;
    Seconds: Real;
  end;

function LongLatToGlobalCoordinate(const LongLat: DWORD): TGlobalCoordinate;
begin
  Result.Degrees := LongLat div (500*60*60);
  Result.Minutes := LongLat div (500*60) - Result.Degrees*60;
  Result.Seconds := LongLat/500 - Result.Minutes*60 - Result.Degrees*60*60;
end;

function GlobalCoordinateToLongLat(const Coord: TGlobalCoordinate): DWORD;
begin
  Result := Round(500*(Coord.Seconds + Coord.Minutes*60 + Coord.Degrees*60*60));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks once again David you have been a tremendous help today.Didn't knew about these damn optimzations can i Remove them from this piece of code ?

Comment: @opc0de You don't want to remove the optimisations. You want to fix your code so that it returns the `min` and `sec` values to the caller. Otherwise why are you bothering to calculate them in the first place?